# OrientDB Cannot delete a vertex after adding a mandatory property

Tags: orientdb

After adding a new mandatory property to a vertex clas,I could not delete the existing records of this class and received the following exception -

```
orientdb {db=VehicleHistoryGraph}> DELETE VERTEX MESSAGE

Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OValidationException: The fie ld 'Message.messageId' is mandatory, but not found on record: Message#26:60742{from:#13:6902,to:#13:6900,text:Test 0: FWD MSG1,in_Forward_Of:[size=3],in_Sent:[size=1],out_Received:[size=1]} v7
```

After removing the mandatory flag I could delete the existing records -

```
orientdb {db=VehicleHistoryGraph}> DELETE VERTEX MESSAGE

Delete record(s) '21' in 0.030000 sec(s).
```

**Is this a feature or a bug of OrientDB?**

Comment: Have you already tried with v2.1.3?

Comment: Nope. Should I uninstall the previous version before installing the new one?

Comment: Just download it and copy the database under `databases/` folder under the new OrientDB server and run the new OrientDB server.